# What does 'a couple of' mean?

Tags: grammar, etymology, phrase-usage

A 'couple' is two of something, typically two people or a matching set of things.

But it seems like there is ambiguity over what 'a couple of' means.  Dictionaries often claim that, 'a couple of' means two as in, 'a couple of friends' and using 'a couple of' as in 'a couple of minutes' to mean several minutes is informal.

However, it seems as though 'a couple of' to mean several is far more common in usage than to mean specifically 'two'. To the extent that I struggle to come up with an example of, 'a couple of' that isn't ambiguous out of context. And 'a couple of' to mean precisely two almost never seems to be used in formal or technical writing.

Furthermore, it seems as though, 'I've made a couple of wine and cheese' is a perfectly fine sentence.

I'm thinking that 'a couple of' is potentially an ambiguous amount to the extent that it could mean almost any number. That is, instead of 'a couple of' meaning 'there are two of this thing,' it means, 'there is a coupling of these things,' and potentially the individual parts of those couples could contain an infinite amount.

Meaning 'a couple of minutes' or 'a couple of biscuits' could mean more than two without it being informal English.

I'm curious if there's a historical/logical/grammatical explanation for why 'a couple of' should mean two.

Comment: I'd dispute that "I've made a couple of wine and cheese" is a valid sentence: you could use "a coupling of wine and cheese" but that's a different expression. "Couple" means "two/pair" or "a few" not a coupling/union. As to the rest of the question, I'd recommend consulting a historical dictionary such as the OED to see how the word was originally used.

Comment: I'd grant that 'a coupling of wine and cheese' is less awkward but I don't really see why you can't have a couple that is made of wine and cheese.

Maybe another example could be a matchmaker saying, "I've made a couple of Jessica and Ryan."

Comment: There is nothing ungrammatical about *a couple of wine and cheese* in the right context. But it would sound confusing. Better would be would be *wine and cheese are a good couple*. The problem with *couple* ***of***, barring a specific context that would indicate otherwise, is that it's associated with a quantity rather than a pairing.

Answer (score 4):

The main meaning and its etymology refer  literally to *two related persons or things*. By extension *a couple* is used to mean “a few”, so more than two:

***[Couple:](https://www.etymonline.com/word/couple)***

> late 13c., ***"two of the same kind or class connected or considered together,"***  especially "a man and a woman associated together by marriage or love," ***from Old French cople "married couple, lovers"*** (12c., Modern French couple), from Latin copula "tie, connection," from PIE *ko-ap-, from *ko(m)- "together" + *ap- "to take, reach." (Etymonline)

Idiom,  ***[a couple of:](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/couple)***

> ***more than two, but not many, of; a small number of; a few:***
>
> - *It will take a couple of days for the package to get there.
>   A dinner party, whether for a couple of old friends or eight new acquaintances, takes nearly the same amount of effort.* (Dictionary.com)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to have come from Latin where it meant "a bond", via Old French ("a pair"). In modern French we also have the vague meaning of "a few" so this is perhaps where/when the idiom came into English. The Latin doesn't seem to suggest any particular number, so could be used for a group of things somehow associated with ("bonded with") one another.

Comment: Can you add a reference?

Answer (score 0):

*Couple* can mean both specifically 2 or a small number (generally not much more than 2, but with no clear upper limit).

The idiom "a couple of" inherits this ambiguity, but it is more often using *couple* in the vaguer sense, so unless context suggested otherwise, it would generally be interpreted as meaning "a small number of".

> Furthermore, it seems as though, 'I've made a couple of wine and cheese' is a perfectly fine sentence.

Even when used in its vaguer sense, it is still only used with countable senses for the noun phrase. Since "wine and cheese" isn't countable, it doesn't work, but you could have a couple of wines (a few different types of wine) or a couple of bottles of wine, and a couple of cheeses (a few different types of cheese).